# Pythonic alternative of stdin/sdtout C code

Tags: python

Code given is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char ch;
  while((ch=getc(stdin))!=EOF)
    putc(ch,stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried:

```
import sys
ch=sys.stdin.read(1)
while (len(ch)>0):
    sys.stdout.write(ch + '\n')
    ch=sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Any better way to implement this code?

Comment: i tried: 
import sys
ch=sys.stdin.read(1)
while (len(ch)>0):
    sys.stdout.write(ch + '\n')
    ch=sys.stdin.read(1)

Comment: @user3223301 Do you really think this is readable? Why don't you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt was pretty close to correct. The problem is the `+ '\n'`. You don't want to write a newline after every single input character. Any newlines in the input will be read and written to the output; that's probably what you want.

```
import sys
ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
while (len(ch)>0):
    sys.stdout.write(ch)
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

You can also loop through `sys.stdin` to read line by line, but if you do, Python will read input in chunks, and you won't see any output until either you've filled up a chunk or entered an EOF:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

We can get more prompt output by using [`sys.stdin.readline`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline), which doesn't use the same chunking mechanism:

```
import sys
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This code uses the uncommon 2-argument form of [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter), which produces an iterator that calls the function supplied as the first argument repeatedly to produce values, stopping when the function produces the value given as the second argument.

Comment: Are you sure,this code would work on python 2.7.x too?

Comment: @user3223301: That's what I ran it on.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python buffers the output until a newline by default, you need to flush after each character:

```
import sys

while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except: break
    for c in line:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Doesn't C buffer the output too?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure this doesn't work. It's going to drop all the newlines, since `raw_input` strips them off.

Comment: After the edit, it works, but writing and flushing each character separately seems a bit silly, and I don't think the flushing makes the program any more correct.